# How to apply sorting in multiple collections with same structure in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb

In my mongodb database have no. of collections with same structure (Actually due to size ,split the original collection in to several collections based on date , every 2 days a new collection will generate ). 
Currently I have to apply sorting and pagination in these collections.

Comment: When you say 'apply sorting', is that during a find()? If so, you need to create the required index for sorting on the collections. For eg. when the collection is first created

Comment: Yes , It is during the find. But If I have 50 collections , How It will work?

Comment: Maybe I'm not following. You just ensure the right sorting index on all collections and do a find() against the right collection. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Actually I need to combine all the collections and need to apply sorting